# How to use QTableWidgetItem text to translate a language translation in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.6

```
 QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget();

 QTableWidgetItem *tw_1 = new QTableWidgetItem();
 tw_1->setText(QObject::tr("Table Name"));
 table->setItem(0,0, tw_1);
```

ru.ts file

```
<context>
    <name>QTableWidgetItem</name>
    <message>
        <source>Table Name</source>
        <translation>Название таблицы</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```

Language translation is not working in QTableWidgetItem.. How to use tranlation here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `QObject::tr("Table Name")` and then you should specify `QObject` in ru.ts file.

```
<context>
    <name>QObject</name>
    <message>
        <source>Table Name</source>
        <translation>Название таблицы</translation>
    </message>
</context>
```